# Django, how to get Choices human friendly text for a choice value with no model instance

Tags: django, django-models

Firstly yes I know about `get_FOO_display()`. It's great if you have a model instance, I don't in my situation.

Im sure every django user at some point wonders why Django uses tuples instead of a dict to define the choices, but anyways, I have this model:

```py
class Review(models.Model):
    PENDING = ''
    APPROVED = 'A'
    DECLINED = 'D'
    SKIPPED = 'S'
    RESULT_CHOICES = (
        (PENDING, 'Pending'),
        (DECLINED, 'Declined'),
        (APPROVED, 'Approved'),
        (SKIPPED, 'Skipped'),
    )
    result = models.CharField('result', max_length=1, choices=RESULT_CHOICES, blank=True, default='')
```

Now I don't have a model instance, but I do have a value, e.g. `A`, or `D`. How do I get the matching text value, i.e. `Approved`, or `Declined` etc. I could build a dict, and then look up the value, but surely theres a more "Built in django" way?

Not looking for this kind of hammer approach:

```py
   human_friendly = [
        PENDING: 'Pending',
        DECLINED: 'Declined',
        APPROVED: 'Approved',
        SKIPPED: 'Skipped',
    ]['A']
```

Answer (score 2):

From version 3.0 you can use an [enumeration type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types) for your choices

```
class Review(models.Model):

    class ResultChoices(models.TextChoices):
        PENDING = '', 'Pending'
        DECLINED = 'D', 'Declined'
        APPROVED = 'A', 'Approved'
        SKIPPED = 'S', 'Skipped'

    result = models.CharField('result', max_length=1, choices=ResultChoices.choices, blank=True, default=ResultChoices.PENDING)

Review.ResultChoices('A') # Review.ResultChoices.APPROVED
Review.ResultChoices('A').label # 'Approved'
```

Comment: This is great thank you! I tried to make an edit to your answer, but the que is full. You forgot to add the human friendly labels to the enum. E.g. `DECLINED = 'D', 'Declined'`

Comment: @run_the_race Ah sorry. The labels should be auto-generated in the correct format based on the name though